# How to get added record (not just the id) through publishAdd()-notification?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Each `Sails.js` model has the method [`publishAdd()`](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#!documentation/reference/ModelMethods/.publishAdd.html). This notifies every listener, when a new record was added to a associated model.

This notification does not contain the newly created record. So I have to start another request from the client side to get the new record.

Is there a possibility, that Sails.js sends the new record with the notification, so I can reduce my request count?

### Solution

I realized the accepted answer like that:
https://gist.github.com/openscript/7016c5fd8c5053b5e3a3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get this record using the default `publishAdd` method.  However, you can override that method and do the child record lookup in your implementation.

You can override `publishAdd` on a per-model basis by adding a `publishAdd` method to that model class, or override it for *all* models by adding the method to the `config/models.js` file.

I would start by [copying the default publishAdd() method](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/pubsub/index.js#L965) and then tweaking as necessary.

Comment: Thank you for this fast and precise answer. I just copied the `publishAdd()` method into my model and replaced `idAdded` with the whole record. In the method body I've replaced all occurrences of `idAdded` with `record.id`. I'm happy!

Comment: I'm thinking about if the whole record is usually more wanted than just the ID? Often the whole record is at the point, where `publishAdd()` is called, available anyway. Would you accept a pull request, with this change? It's possible to make this backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I just had to solve this again, and didn't like the idea of dropping in duplicate code so if someone is looking for alternative, the trick is to update the model of the newly created record with an afterCreate: method.

Say you have a Game that you want to your Players to subscribe to. Games have notifications, a collection of text alerts that you only want players in the game to receive. To do this, subscribe to Game on the client by requesting it. Here I'm getting a particular game by calling game/gameId, then building my page based on what notifications and players are already on the model:

```
io.socket.get('/game/'+gameId, function(resData, jwres) {
    let players = resData.players;
    let notifications = resData.notifications;
    $.each(players, function (k,v) {
        if(v.id!=playerId){
            addPartyMember(v);
        }
    });
    $.each(notifications, function (k,v) {
        addNotification(v.text);
    });
});
```

Subscribed to game will only give the id's, as we know, but when I add a notification, I have both the Game Id and the notification record, so I can add the following to the Notification model:

```
afterCreate: function (newlyCreatedRecord, cb) {
    Game.publishAdd(newlyCreatedRecord.game,'notifications',newlyCreatedRecord);
cb();}
```

Since my original socket.get subscribes to a particular game, I can publish only to those subscriber by using Game.publishAdd(). Now back on the client side, listen for the data coming back:

```
io.socket.on('game', function (event) { 
if (event.attribute == 'notifications') {
    addNotification(event.added.text);
    }
});
```

The incoming records will look something like this:

```
 {"id":"59fdd1439aee4e031e61f91f",
 "verb":"addedTo",
"attribute" :"notifications",
 "addedId":"59fef31ba264a60e2a88e5c1",
 "added":{"game":"59fdd1439aee4e031e61f91f",
 "text":"some messages",
 "createdAt":"2017-11-05T11:16:43.488Z",
 "updatedAt":"2017-11-05T11:16:43.488Z",
 "id":"59fef31ba264a60e2a88e5c1"}}
```