# Filtering socket.io subscriptions

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

Imagine I have a `User` model and also a `Message` model. User has many messages.

Then in the client I do a:

```
io.socket.get('/user/2/messages'....
```

I get all my user messages and there is no problem trying to get someones else messages because I have a policy for that. Good.

I want to listen if the user has new messages, if I do a:

```
io.socket.on('message')
```

I get every message created, mine or not mine.

So: Can I listen just for MY messages? AKA listen for associated messages but not all of them.

Maybe using a policy or something for just that. Because even if there is a way to listen to them, anyone can modify the client to listen to what he wants to, I need to filter all of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.  The trick is to listen for *user* events with the "addedTo" verb, rather than listening directly for message creation.  The code would be something like:

```
io.socket.on('user', function(msg) {

    if (msg.verb == 'addedTo' && msg.attribute == 'messages') {

        // A new message was added to the user's "messages" collection
        var messageId = msg.addedId
        // From here you can request /message/[messageId] to get the
        // message details if you need them

    }

});
```

More info on the [.publishAdd() doc page](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Models/Model-Methods/publishAdd.html).

Note that only the ID of the added message is given; you may find you want the whole thing.  You can handle that by either making a separate request for the new message, or overriding `publishAdd` as is [suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774743/how-to-get-added-record-not-just-the-id-through-publishadd-notification/23775805#comment36574692_23775805).

The only catch here is to make sure you're limiting who gets subscribed to those user events.  It sounds like you have a policy in place that prevents users from accessing **/user/:id/messages** for other users.  You'll want want preventing them from accessing **/user/:id** for other users as well (at least via sockets), since they will be subscribed to any user they access that way.

If this is undesirable--that is, if you'd *like* people to be able to hit those routes--then an alternative would be to use the `autoSubscribe` model property to restrict the automatic subscription that blueprints normally do.  `autoSubscribe` is normally set to `true`, which means that any time a socket request is made for a model, the requesting socket will be subscribed to all events for that model instance.  You can instead set it to an array of *contexts* that should be subscribed to.  Contexts are specific events you're interested in, like `update` or `destroy` (more about contexts [in the docs](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Models/Model-Methods/subscribe.html)).  Finally, you can set `autoSubscribe` to `false` to restrict subscription to that model entirely.  Then you can just subscribe manually with `.subscribe()` whenever you want to listen for events.

You can see some examples of contexts and `autoSubscribe` in action in the [sailsChat](http://github.com/balderdashy/sailsChat) sample app.