# How to catch the event of a linked collection having an UPDATE via autosubscribe pub/sub?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have scoured the internet madly for this and these are the posts that seem to relate to what I'm trying to do the most:

[sails js cheatsheet](http://www.cheatography.com/proloser/cheat-sheets/sailsjs/pdf/)

[How to get added record (not just the id) through publishAdd()-notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774743/how-to-get-added-record-not-just-the-id-through-publishadd-notification)

[Filtering socket.io subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791966/filtering-socket-io-subscriptions)

but they don't quite help

I have 
**Model Rooms**

```
autosubscribe:['add:people','update:people']
attributes:{
     people:{collection:'people',via:'room'},
     temp:{type:'integer'}
},
```

**Model People**

```
 attributes: {
      name:{type:'string'},
      room:{model:'rooms'},
      status:{type:'string',enum:['frustratedWithOfficialDocumentationBeingSoFracturedBetween:HiddenGitHubs_GoogleMisdirectsOnWebsite_OldYoutubes_ConceptsReferenceWhichAreForNoReasonSplitUp','personIsDead']
 },
```

Now, lets say that instead of adding another person in a room (which could fire the publishAdd event) I have found that one of my people has died and I need to simply update their status

```
People.findOne({name:'mrHappy'}).exec(err,mrHappyObj){
    mrHappyObj.status = 'personIsDead'
    mrHappyObj.save()  //etc
    People.publishUpdate(mrHappyObj.id,{status:mrHappyObj.status})
})
```

So this is great for everyone subscribed to 'mrHappy' but it would be so awesome if I could find the thing that would tell the ROOM he was associated with that he was dead automatically, I don't care if whatever it is only gives me mrHappy's id, I would really like to get notified automatically.

*bonus stuff that I tried but not necessary to read.*
I wrote this function in my People model but it seems very kludgy

```
afterUpdate: function(updatedRecord, next)
 {
 sails.log.debug("I updated a People! derp",updatedRecord);
 sails.log.debug("key is ",sails.models[this.identity].primaryKey);
        var pKey = sails.models[this.identity].primaryKey
 var thisModelId = this.identity
        _.each(Z.getAssociationParents(this.identity), function(association) {
    // //so we now have the name of a parent model, we now have to find the id() of the parent that this
    // //NEW thing is pointing to?
    // //This is the parent that needs to be notified that he now owns a new vehicle. We have to take 
    // //the socket in his room and then use it to subscribe to this change!
//                 console.log("parent model found:",association)
                sails.log.debug("parent room",'sails_model_'+association+'s_'+ updatedRecord[association]+':'+'update')
                var sockets = sails.sockets.subscribers('sails_model_'+association+'s_'+ updatedRecord[association]+':'+'update')


                sails.log.debug("child room",'sails_model_'+thisModelId+'_'+ updatedRecord[pKey] +':'+'update')
                var deleteMeSocketsInChild = sails.sockets.subscribers('sails_model_'+thisModelId+'_'+ updatedRecord[pKey] +':'+'update')

                sails.log.debug("sockets in parent:", sockets, "child:",deleteMeSocketsInChild)

                for(var s in sockets)
                {
                    var sock = sails.io.sockets.socket(sockets[s]);

 //TODO !! send the subscribe method the needed primary key object
                    sails.models[thisModelId].subscribe(sock, Z.subscribePluralizer(pKey,updatedRecord[pKey])); //TODO - get the primary key as the last paramater to this function (updaterd record
 sails.log.debug("break")
    //   //could pass it a null


    // //If i am correct, updatedRecord is the whole record that has been updated. We are wanting to 
    // //subscribe the parent socket(s) to it. If this doesn't work , try using the information within
    // //the udpatedRecord to do the subscribe unless you can think of a better way.
 sails.log.debug("sockets in parent:", sockets, " NEW child:",deleteMeSocketsInChild)
                }

        });
 next()
 }
```

the other functions

```
 //return the models that are your parents
 getAssociationParents: function(modelName) {
 var assocArr = []
 if (sails.models[modelName]) {
 for (var a in sails.models[modelName].attributes) {
 if (sails.models[modelName].attributes[a].model)
 assocArr.push(a)
 }
 }
 return assocArr
 },


 //inspired by the pluralize function in \sails\lib\hooks\pubsub\index.js - we have to wrap our primary key up all pretty for it
 // since we don't expect our updatedRecords function to return an array of new objects (it shouldn't) we won't use the _.map function from pluralize
 subscribePluralizer: function(pKey, value) {
 //this function should be examined before using - 1-28-2015
 var newObj = {}
 newObj[pKey] = value
 newObj = [newObj]


 return newObj
 },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm open to suggestions here. but this works a treat

you can put this in your model (or ideally package it up in a service or something)

```
  afterUpdate:function(updated,cb){
    var self = this
    Z.publishParentUpdate(updated,self, function(err){
        if(err){sails.log.debug(self.identity,'afterUpdate error',err)}
        try{
            sails.models[self.identity].publishUpdate(updated.id,updated)
            cb()
        }catch(err){sails.log.warn('error at end of afterupdate!',err)}
    })
  }
```

**and then these bad boys in your services, I use Z.js for mine**

```
publishParentUpdate:function(updatedObj,theThis,cb){
        //iterate over all the attributes that have a model key in the attributes of this model
        var error = null
        _.each(Z.getAssociationParents(theThis.identity), function(association) {
            var parentModel = sails.models[theThis.attributes[association].model]  //we can use this to directly address the parent model and do its finds / updates
            var embeddedUpdateObj = {} //container for the object that we are going to fake the update message with
            embeddedUpdateObj[theThis.identity]=updatedObj //set the updated properties inside the model
            try{ //probably don't need to try catch, but since we could make a mistake assuming some things above it seems smarter
                parentModel.publishUpdate(updatedObj[association],embeddedUpdateObj) //updating based on the id contained in our model and then packing in our happy object
            }catch(err){
                sails.log.warn('error while doing a collection update',err)
                error = err
            }
            cb(error)
        });
    },

    getAssociations: function(modelName) { //modelName is string!
        //function returns
        var assocArr = []
        if (sails.models[modelName]) {
            for (var a in sails.models[modelName].attributes) {
                if (sails.models[modelName].attributes[a].collection)
                    assocArr.push(a)
            }
        }
        return assocArr
    },

    //return the models that are your parents
    getAssociationParents: function(modelName) {
        var assocArr = []
        if (sails.models[modelName]) {
            for (var a in sails.models[modelName].attributes) {
                if (sails.models[modelName].attributes[a].model)
                    assocArr.push(a)
            }
        }
        return assocArr
    },
```